# list index out of range with if condition

Tags: python, arrays

```
num_array = list()
num = int(raw_input("Enter how many elements you want:"))
print 'Enter numbers in array: '
for i in range(int(num)):
    n = raw_input("num :")
    num_array.append(int(n))
print 'ARRAY: ',num_array
b = 0
count = 0
while b< num -1 or b>0:
    count = count+1
    if num_array[b]!= 0:
        b =  b + num_array[b]
    else:
        b = (b + num_array[b])*2
print count
```

i am trying to get an array as an input anD storing a index value in a variable which is updating its values. But i am getting an error of **list out of range**

Please help me

Comment: Post your code here with proper format, not as an image.

Comment: ya sure...it was by mistake

Comment: Post your code WITH PROPER format, we need to be able to copy and paste your code.. Also you didn't describe what your code is doing... and what it should be doing

Answer (score 1):

Your condition `while b < num-1 or b>0` does not make sense. The `or b>0` part makes it `True` for all values larger than `num-1`. Instead, you should use `and`:

```
while b < num-1 and b > 0:
```

Or shorter, using comparison chaining:

```
while 0 < b < num-1:
```

Also, note that array indices go from `0` to `num-1` (`num` being the length), so actually the condition should probably be (not tested, though):

```
while 0 <= b < num:
```

Comment: Thanks Tobias...It worked

Comment: @prtkpande If this solved your problem, please consider _accepting_ the answer to mark the question as being resolved.